# WCF self hosted service configuration

Tags: wcf, get

I have a very simple WCF service that is hosted within a windows application. I'm tring to access the service by using **GET** method but just getting an empty page. I guess there is something wrong with configuration but I could't figure out what. Here is the codes:

**WCFService.cs**

```
namespace WCFServiceApp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class WCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public int GetNumbers()
        {
            return 12345;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
private static Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8090");
private ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), baseAddress);

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host.Open();
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
              <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                <webHttp />
              </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior">
              <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFService">
              </endpoint>
              <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFService">
              </endpoint>
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I hit **localhost:8090** with browser I see WCF welcome page. When I hit **localhost:8090/GetNumbers** just getting an empty page instead of the numbers.